# Ubuntu and HP scanning

Tags: hp, scanner, scanning

Help! just installed Ubuntu to replace XP. Excellent so far, except Ubuntu will not accept the install disc for my HP Deskjet F4580. It has recognised the item and allowed me to print even before I tried the disc. Now I wish to scan documents and I can't do this without the HP software installed. It keeps telling me the Archive manager has an error when I try to get it to read the HP disc.It has the HP menu but not start the Set Up process. Is there a remedy please. I really use my scanner a lot and am now lost. Any useful comments please. Stuart

Comment: You can try to install **simple-scan** which is available in Ubuntu software center.

Comment: The install disk is for Windows and Macs. It will never work with Ubuntu.

Comment: Install `hplip-gui` and `simple-scan` from the Ubuntu Software Center. The first will let you setup your printer. Open the `simple-scan` program when you want to scan a document. Ubuntu does not support scanning directly from the printer.

Comment: @user68186 Your comment really helped me. Thanks. This should be the accepted answer

Comment: @CesarLeonardoOchoaContreras I am glad I could help. Thanks for the comment. I have now turned my comment to an answer. I don't think the original poster is active in this site any more. You can up-vote my answer if you like.

Answer (score 9):

## Step 1: Install `hplip-gui`

This app does not show up in Ubuntu Software Center. However, it can be installed from the terminal or `synaptic`. To install it from the terminal open a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and enter:

```
sudo apt install hplip-gui
```

Enter your password when prompted. You won't see the cursor move or `*******` when you type the password in the terminal. This is normal.

## Step 2: Install `simple-scan`

This is the scanning utility for Ubuntu. You can either install it from the **Ubuntu Software Center** or from the terminal. At the terminal, enter:

```
sudo apt install simple-scan
```

## Or Combine the 2 Steps

You can use one command to install both the software:

```
sudo apt install hplip-gui simple-scan
```

## To Scan a Document

Open the `simple-scan` program when you want to scan a document. Ubuntu does not support scanning directly from the printer.

Hope this helps

Comment: I additionally needed to run a "hp-setup" command, change from USB to Network, push Next, Next and Finish  to have my scanner recognized in the simple-scan.

Answer (score 0):

The install disk that came with your printer would be for windows, perhaps even mac.  This will not work for you.

You should just be able to go here and follow the instructions and it should work if you are connected directly.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ScanningHowTo

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

**hplip + simple-scan** work really great!!! (as long as your `hplip` version is [compatible](https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/supported_devices/index) with your printer)

```
sudo apt install hplip simple-scan
```

[image]

---

The problem I had is that when I tried to scan from the feeder it just kept scanning from the flatbead instead, over and over again

Then I realized my hplip version was a bit old and didn't support my new printer, that's why it wasn't recognizing it and Ubuntu was using a generic driver. [Check compatibility here](https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/supported_devices/index) (`apt show hplip | grep -i version` to see your hplip version)

You can manually install the newest **hplip** here https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/gethplip

---

BTW, although hplip's software didn't recognize my network printer, **simple-scan** did recognize a new device